# Does io() for socket.io always open a new connection?

Tags: socket.io

If I open a socket connection like this:

```
socket = io('localhost');
```

Will I have to pass the socket around the entire application or can I keep calling `io('localhost')` for the same connection?

Answer (score 0):

When using the "standalone" build of Socket.io's client library:

```
var socket = io("http://localhost");
```

This associates the variable socket with an instance of Socket. It represents your connection, you can use it like

```
socket.on("news", data => console.log(data));
```

So it makes sense to either register "socket" as a global variable - or pass it around to the parts where it's needed. Recalling io("...") every time you need it might work, but but it would be an unnecessary overhead.